Jest encountered an unexpected token. dataformat
I use jest for tests on my project and I  had received an error after I  started my test.
It has started after I had added dataformat to my project
Code of error:
Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    C:\Users\maxos\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\diary-app\node_modules\dateformat\lib\dateformat.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){var token=/d{1,4}|D{3,4}|m{1,4}|yy(?:yy)?|([HhMsTt])\1?|W{1,2}|[LlopSZN]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*'/g;var timezone=/\b(?:[A-Z]{1,3}[A-Z][TC])(?:[-+]\d{4})?|((?:Australian )?(?:Pacific|Mountain|Central|Eastern|Atlantic) (?:Standard|Daylight|Prevailing) Time)\b/g;var timezoneClip=/[^-+\dA-Z]/g;export default function dateFormat(date,mask,utc,gmt){if(arguments.length===1&&typeof date==="string"&&!/\d/.test(date)){mask=date;date=undefined}date=date||date===0?date:new Date;if(!(date instanceof Date)){date=new Date(date)}if(isNaN(date)){throw TypeError("Invalid date")}mask=String(masks[mask]||mask||masks["default"]);var maskSlice=mask.slice(0,4);if(maskSlice==="UTC:"||maskSlice==="GMT:"){mask=mask.slice(4);utc=true;if(maskSlice==="GMT:"){gmt=true}}var _=function _(){return utc?"getUTC":"get"};var _d=function d(){return date[_()+"Date"]()};var D=function D(){return date[_()+"Day"]()};var _m=function m(){return date[_()+"Month"]()};var y=function y(){return date[_()+"FullYear"]()};var _H=function H(){return date[_()+"Hours"]()};var _M=function M(){return date[_()+"Minutes"]()};var _s=function s(){return date[_()+"Seconds"]()};var _L=function L(){return date[_()+"Milliseconds"]()};var _o=function o(){return utc?0:date.getTimezoneOffset()};var _W=function W(){return getWeek(date)};var _N=function N(){return getDayOfWeek(date)};var flags={d:function d(){return _d()},dd:function dd(){return pad(_d())},ddd:function ddd(){return i18n.dayNames[D()]},DDD:function DDD(){return getDayName({y:y(),m:_m(),d:_d(),_:_(),dayName:i18n.dayNames[D()],short:true})},dddd:function dddd(){return i18n.dayNames[D()+7]},DDDD:function DDDD(){return getDayName({y:y(),m:_m(),d:_d(),_:_(),dayName:i18n.dayNames[D()+7]})},m:function m(){return _m()+1},mm:function mm(){return pad(_m()+1)},mmm:function mmm(){return i18n.monthNames[_m()]},mmmm:function mmmm(){return i18n.monthNames[_m()+12]},yy:function yy(){return String(y()).slice(2)},yyyy:function yyyy(){return pad(y(),4)},h:function h(){return _H()%12||12},hh:function hh(){return pad(_H()%12||12)},H:function H(){return _H()},HH:function HH(){return pad(_H())},M:function M(){return _M()},MM:function MM(){return pad(_M())},s:function s(){return _s()},ss:function ss(){return pad(_s())},l:function l(){return pad(_L(),3)},L:function L(){return pad(Math.floor(_L()/10))},t:function t(){return _H()<12?i18n.timeNames[0]:i18n.timeNames[1]},tt:function tt(){return _H()<12?i18n.timeNames[2]:i18n.timeNames[3]},T:function T(){return _H()<12?i18n.timeNames[4]:i18n.timeNames[5]},TT:function TT(){return _H()<12?i18n.timeNames[6]:i18n.timeNames[7]},Z:function Z(){return gmt?"GMT":utc?"UTC":formatTimezone(date)},o:function o(){return(_o()>0?"-":"+")+pad(Math.floor(Math.abs(_o())/60)*100+Math.abs(_o())%60,4)},p:function p(){return(_o()>0?"-":"+")+pad(Math.floor(Math.abs(_o())/60),2)+":"+pad(Math.floor(Math.abs(_o())%60),2)},S:function S(){return["th","st","nd","rd"][_d()%10>3?0:(_d()%100-_d()%10!=10)*_d()%10]},W:function W(){return _W()},WW:function WW(){return pad(_W())},N:function N(){return _N()}};return mask.replace(token,function(match){if(match in flags){return flags[match]()}return match.slice(1,match.length-1)})}export var masks={default:"ddd mmm dd yyyy HH:MM:ss",shortDate:"m/d/yy",paddedShortDate:"mm/dd/yyyy",mediumDate:"mmm d, yyyy",longDate:"mmmm d, yyyy",fullDate:"dddd, mmmm d, yyyy",shortTime:"h:MM TT",mediumTime:"h:MM:ss TT",longTime:"h:MM:ss TT Z",isoDate:"yyyy-mm-dd",isoTime:"HH:MM:ss",isoDateTime:"yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:sso",isoUtcDateTime:"UTC:yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss'Z'",expiresHeaderFormat:"ddd, dd mmm yyyy HH:MM:ss Z"};export var i18n={dayNames:["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"],monthNames:["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],timeNames:["a","p","am","pm","A","P","AM","PM"]};var pad=function pad(val){var len=arguments.length>1&&arguments[1]!==undefined?arguments[1]:2;return String(val).padStart(len,"0")};var getDayName=function getDayName(_ref){var y=_ref.y,m=_ref.m,d=_ref.d,_=_ref._,dayName=_ref.dayName,_ref$short=_ref["short"],_short=_ref$short===void 0?false:_ref$short;var today=new Date;var yesterday=new Date;yesterday.setDate(yesterday[_+"Date"]()-1);var tomorrow=new Date;tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow[_+"Date"]()+1);var today_d=function today_d(){return today[_+"Date"]()};var today_m=function today_m(){return today[_+"Month"]()};var today_y=function today_y(){return today[_+"FullYear"]()};var yesterday_d=function yesterday_d(){return yesterday[_+"Date"]()};var yesterday_m=function yesterday_m(){return yesterday[_+"Month"]()};var yesterday_y=function yesterday_y(){return yesterday[_+"FullYear"]()};var tomorrow_d=function tomorrow_d(){return tomorrow[_+"Date"]()};var tomorrow_m=function tomorrow_m(){return tomorrow[_+"Month"]()};var tomorrow_y=function tomorrow_y(){return tomorrow[_+"FullYear"]()};if(today_y()===y&&today_m()===m&&today_d()===d){return _short?"Tdy":"Today"}else if(yesterday_y()===y&&yesterday_m()===m&&yesterday_d()===d){return _short?"Ysd":"Yesterday"}else if(tomorrow_y()===y&&tomorrow_m()===m&&tomorrow_d()===d){return _short?"Tmw":"Tomorrow"}return dayName};var getWeek=function getWeek(date){var targetThursday=new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth(),date.getDate());targetThursday.setDate(targetThursday.getDate()-(targetThursday.getDay()+6)%7+3);var firstThursday=new Date(targetThursday.getFullYear(),0,4);firstThursday.setDate(firstThursday.getDate()-(firstThursday.getDay()+6)%7+3);var ds=targetThursday.getTimezoneOffset()-firstThursday.getTimezoneOffset();targetThursday.setHours(targetThursday.getHours()-ds);var weekDiff=(targetThursday-firstThursday)/(864e5*7);return 1+Math.floor(weekDiff)};var getDayOfWeek=function getDayOfWeek(date){var dow=date.getDay();if(dow===0){dow=7}return dow};export var formatTimezone=function formatTimezone(date){return(String(date).match(timezone)||[""]).pop().replace(timezoneClip,"").replace(/GMT\+0000/g,"UTC")};
                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                   ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

       8 | import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Delete';
       9 | import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
    > 10 | import dateFormat, { masks } from "dateformat";
         | ^
      11 |
      12 | export const TaskComponent: React.FC<ITaskComponentProps> = ({ task }) => {
      13 |   const theme = useTheme()

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)
      at Object.require (libs/web/main/src/lib/features-MainPage/components/TaskComponents/TaskComponent.tsx:10:1)
      at Object.require (libs/web/main/src/lib/ui-MainPage/MainPage.tsx:7:1)
      at Object.require (libs/web/main/src/lib/utils-testing/Main.test.tsx:3:1)

it is my jest.config.ts:
import { getJestProjects } from '@nx/jest';

export default {
  projects: getJestProjects(),
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@diary-app/shared': '<rootDir>/libs/web/shared/src/index.ts',
    'globalShared': '<rootDir>/libs/global/src/index.ts',
    uuid: require.resolve('uuid'),
  },
  transform: {
    '^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)': '@nrwl/react/plugins/jest',
    '^.+\\.[tj]sx?$': ['babel-jest', { presets: ['@nrwl/react/babel'] }],
  },
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["@testing-library/jest-dom", "./jest.setup.ts"],
  setupFiles: ['./jest.polyfills.js'],
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    customExportConditions: [""],
  },
  
};

I tried to fix it by adding: dateformat: require.resolve('dateformat') in moduleNameMapper but it does not work. I would be glad of help, thanks in advance.
